# .addEventListener is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Someone has helped me with this script in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNvobY) where it worked fine, until i tried to implement it into my Wordpress website.

*The two sets of grey dots are buttons. Each button will open it's own slide menu.*

---

On the console I receive this specific error. "**openbtn.addEventListener is not a function**"

Which is in relation to this code:

*In codepen the error is located on line 104*

```
<script>
 /*!
  * classie - class helper functions
  * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
  * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
  * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
  * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
  */

 /*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
 /*global define: false */

 (function (window) {

     'use strict';

     // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

     function classReg(className) {
         return new RegExp("(^|s+)" + className + "(s+|$)");
     }

     // classList support for class management
     // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
     var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

     if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
         hasClass = function (elem, c) {
             return elem.classList.contains(c);
         };
         addClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.classList.add(c);
         };
         removeClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.classList.remove(c);
         };
     } else {
         hasClass = function (elem, c) {
             return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
         };
         addClass = function (elem, c) {
             if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
                 elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
             }
         };
         removeClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
         };
     }

     function toggleClass(elem, c) {
         var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
         fn(elem, c);
     }

     var classie = {
         // full names
         hasClass: hasClass,
         addClass: addClass,
         removeClass: removeClass,
         toggleClass: toggleClass,
         // short names
         has: hasClass,
         add: addClass,
         remove: removeClass,
         toggle: toggleClass
     };

     // transport
     if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
         // AMD
         define(classie);
     } else {
         // browser global
         window.classie = classie;
     }

 })(window);


 /**
  * main.js
  * http://www.codrops.com
  *
  * Licensed under the MIT license.
  * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  * 
  * Copyright 2014, Codrops
  * http://www.codrops.com
  */ (function () {

     var bodyEl = document.body,
         content = document.querySelector('.content-wrap'),
         openbtn = $(".menu-button").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".menu-wrap").toggleClass("show-menu");
}),
         closebtn = document.getElementById('close-button'),
         isOpen = false;

     function init() {
         initEvents();
     }

     function initEvents() {
         openbtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
         if (closebtn) {
             closebtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
         }

         // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
         content.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
             var target = ev.target;
             if (isOpen && target !== openbtn) {
                 toggleMenu();
             }
         });
     }

     function toggleMenu() {
         if (isOpen) {
             classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
         } else {
             classie.add(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
         }
         isOpen = !isOpen;
     }

     init();

 })();</script>
```

I have researched where people have had similar issues with .addeventlistener, but literally all of their solutions were executed differently specific to their code. How can I resolve this issue while retaining the purpose of the code?

**HTML OF WEBSITE**

```
<html lang="en-US" class="js"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://generation-co.co/xmlrpc.php">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
<title>Generation | Beta</title>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Generation » Feed" href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/feed/">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Generation » Comments Feed" href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/comments/feed/">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/72x72\/","ext":".png","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/generation-co.co\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.4"}};
            !function(a,b,c){function d(a){var c=b.createElement("canvas"),d=c.getContext&&c.getContext("2d");return d&&d.fillText?(d.textBaseline="top",d.font="600 32px Arial","flag"===a?(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55356,56812,55356,56807),0,0),c.toDataURL().length>3e3):(d.fillText(String.fromCharCode(55357,56835),0,0),0!==d.getImageData(16,16,1,1).data[0])):!1}function e(a){var c=b.createElement("script");c.src=a,c.type="text/javascript",b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)}var f,g;c.supports={simple:d("simple"),flag:d("flag")},c.DOMReady=!1,c.readyCallback=function(){c.DOMReady=!0},c.supports.simple&&c.supports.flag||(g=function(){c.readyCallback()},b.addEventListener?(b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",g,!1),a.addEventListener("load",g,!1)):(a.attachEvent("onload",g),b.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===b.readyState&&c.readyCallback()})),f=c.source||{},f.concatemoji?e(f.concatemoji):f.wpemoji&&f.twemoji&&(e(f.twemoji),e(f.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script><script src="http://generation-co.co/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.2.4" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="parent-style-css" href="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/style.css?ver=4.2.4" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="child-style-css" href="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/generation-1-1/style.css?ver=4.2.4" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="twentyfifteen-fonts-css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans%3A400italic%2C700italic%2C400%2C700%7CNoto+Serif%3A400italic%2C700italic%2C400%2C700%7CInconsolata%3A400%2C700&amp;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="genericons-css" href="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/_inc/genericons/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.1" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="twentyfifteen-style-css" href="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/generation-1-1/style.css?ver=4.2.4" type="text/css" media="all">
<style id="twentyfifteen-style-inline-css" type="text/css">

        /* Custom Sidebar Text Color */
        .site-title a,
        .site-description,
        .secondary-toggle:before {
            color: #ffffff;
        }

        .site-title a:hover,
        .site-title a:focus {
            color: #ffffff; /* Fallback for IE7 and IE8 */
            color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        }

        .secondary-toggle {
            border-color: #ffffff; /* Fallback for IE7 and IE8 */
            border-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        }

        .secondary-toggle:hover,
        .secondary-toggle:focus {
            border-color: #ffffff; /* Fallback for IE7 and IE8 */
            border-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }

        .site-title a {
            outline-color: #ffffff; /* Fallback for IE7 and IE8 */
            outline-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3);
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em) {
            .secondary a,
            .dropdown-toggle:after,
            .widget-title,
            .widget blockquote cite,
            .widget blockquote small {
                color: #ffffff;
            }

            .widget button,
            .widget input[type="button"],
            .widget input[type="reset"],
            .widget input[type="submit"],
            .widget_calendar tbody a {
                background-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .textwidget a {
                border-color: #ffffff;
            }

            .secondary a:hover,
            .secondary a:focus,
            .main-navigation .menu-item-description,
            .widget,
            .widget blockquote,
            .widget .wp-caption-text,
            .widget .gallery-caption {
                color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            }

            .widget button:hover,
            .widget button:focus,
            .widget input[type="button"]:hover,
            .widget input[type="button"]:focus,
            .widget input[type="reset"]:hover,
            .widget input[type="reset"]:focus,
            .widget input[type="submit"]:hover,
            .widget input[type="submit"]:focus,
            .widget_calendar tbody a:hover,
            .widget_calendar tbody a:focus {
                background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            }

            .widget blockquote {
                border-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.7);
            }

            .main-navigation ul,
            .main-navigation li,
            .secondary-toggle,
            .widget input,
            .widget textarea,
            .widget table,
            .widget th,
            .widget td,
            .widget pre,
            .widget li,
            .widget_categories .children,
            .widget_nav_menu .sub-menu,
            .widget_pages .children,
            .widget abbr[title] {
                border-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
            }

            .dropdown-toggle:hover,
            .dropdown-toggle:focus,
            .widget hr {
                background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1);
            }

            .widget input:focus,
            .widget textarea:focus {
                border-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            }

            .sidebar a:focus,
            .dropdown-toggle:focus {
                outline-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.3);
            }
        }

</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfifteen-ie-css'  href='http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/css/ie.css?ver=20141010' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyfifteen-ie7-css'  href='http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/css/ie7.css?ver=20141010' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://generation-co.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.2"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://generation-co.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1"></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://generation-co.co/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://generation-co.co/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.4">
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
    <style type="text/css" id="twentyfifteen-header-css">
            .site-header {
            padding-top: 14px;
            padding-bottom: 14px;
        }

        .site-branding {
            min-height: 42px;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 46.25em) {
            .site-header {
                padding-top: 21px;
                padding-bottom: 21px;
            }
            .site-branding {
                min-height: 56px;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
            .site-header {
                padding-top: 25px;
                padding-bottom: 25px;
            }
            .site-branding {
                min-height: 62px;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 59.6875em) {
            .site-header {
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }
            .site-branding {
                min-height: 0;
            }
        }
            .site-title,
        .site-description {
            clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
            position: absolute;
        }
        </style>
    <style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #ffffff; }
</style>
</head>

<body class="home blog custom-background">
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>

    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar" style="position: fixed;">
        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
            <div class="site-branding">
                                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="https://generation-co.co/" rel="home">Generation</a></h1>
                                            <p class="site-description">Beta</p>
                                    <button class="secondary-toggle">Menu and widgets</button>
            </div><!-- .site-branding -->
        </header><!-- .site-header -->

            <div id="secondary" class="secondary">



                    <div id="widget-area" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
                <aside id="search-2" class="widget widget_search"><form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://generation-co.co/">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" title="Search for:">
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit screen-reader-text" value="Search">
            </form></aside>     <aside id="recent-posts-2" class="widget widget_recent_entries">        <h2 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h2>      <ul>
                    <li>
                <a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/17/test-2/">Test 2</a>
                        </li>
                    <li>
                <a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/15/wordpress-resources-at-siteground/">WordPress Resources at SiteGround</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
        </aside><aside id="recent-comments-2" class="widget widget_recent_comments"><h2 class="widget-title">Recent Comments</h2><ul id="recentcomments"><li class="recentcomments"><span class="comment-author-link"><a href="https://wordpress.org/" rel="external nofollow" class="url">Mr WordPress</a></span> on <a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/15/wordpress-resources-at-siteground/#comment-1">WordPress Resources at SiteGround</a></li></ul></aside><aside id="archives-2" class="widget widget_archive"><h2 class="widget-title">Archives</h2>       <ul>
    <li><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/">August 2015</a></li>
        </ul>
</aside><aside id="categories-2" class="widget widget_categories"><h2 class="widget-title">Categories</h2>      <ul>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/category/uncategorized/">Uncategorized</a>
</li>
        </ul>
</aside>
<!-- Start - HTML Javascript Adder plugin v3.9 -->
<aside id="html_javascript_adder-3" class="widget widget_html_javascript_adder">
<div class="hjawidget textwidget">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 /*!
  * classie - class helper functions
  * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
  * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
  * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
  * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
  */

 /*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
 /*global define: false */

 (function (window) {

     'use strict';

     // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

     function classReg(className) {
         return new RegExp("(^|s+)" + className + "(s+|$)");
     }

     // classList support for class management
     // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
     var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

     if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
         hasClass = function (elem, c) {
             return elem.classList.contains(c);
         };
         addClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.classList.add(c);
         };
         removeClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.classList.remove(c);
         };
     } else {
         hasClass = function (elem, c) {
             return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
         };
         addClass = function (elem, c) {
             if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
                 elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
             }
         };
         removeClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
         };
     }

     function toggleClass(elem, c) {
         var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
         fn(elem, c);
     }

     var classie = {
         // full names
         hasClass: hasClass,
         addClass: addClass,
         removeClass: removeClass,
         toggleClass: toggleClass,
         // short names
         has: hasClass,
         add: addClass,
         remove: removeClass,
         toggle: toggleClass
     };

     // transport
     if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
         // AMD
         define(classie);
     } else {
         // browser global
         window.classie = classie;
     }

 })(window);


 /**
  * main.js
  * http://www.codrops.com
  *
  * Licensed under the MIT license.
  * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  * 
  * Copyright 2014, Codrops
  * http://www.codrops.com
  */ (function () {

     var bodyEl = document.body,
         content = document.querySelector('.content-wrap'),
         openbtn = $(".menu-button").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".menu-wrap").toggleClass("show-menu");
}),
         closebtn = document.getElementById('close-button'),
         isOpen = false;

     function init() {
         initEvents();
     }

     function initEvents() {
         openbtn = $(".menu-button");
openbtn.click(function () {
       $(this).next(".menu-wrap").toggleClass("show-menu");
});
         if (closebtn) {
             closebtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
         }

         // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
         content.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
             var target = ev.target;
             if (isOpen && target !== openbtn) {
                 toggleMenu();
             }
         });
     }

     function toggleMenu() {
         if (isOpen) {
             classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
         } else {
             classie.add(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
         }
         isOpen = !isOpen;
     }

     init();

 })();</script>
</div>
</aside><!-- End - HTML Javascript Adder plugin v3.9 -->
<aside id="meta-2" class="widget widget_meta"><h2 class="widget-title">Meta</h2>            <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://generation-co.co/wp-login.php">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/feed/">Entries <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/comments/feed/">Comments <abbr title="Really Simple Syndication">RSS</abbr></a></li>
<li><a href="https://wordpress.org/" title="Powered by WordPress, state-of-the-art semantic personal publishing platform.">WordPress.org</a></li>           </ul>
</aside>            </div><!-- .widget-area -->

    </div><!-- .secondary -->

    </div><!-- .sidebar -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">




<article id="post-3" class="post-3 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/17/test-2/" rel="bookmark">Test 2</a></h2>  </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p><img src="https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t51.2885-15/11809878_119652368381343_624710955_n.jpg" width="1080" height="1080" class="aligncenter"></p>
<p><br>
<button class="menu-button">Open Menu</button></p>
<div class="menu-wrap"></div>
<p><button class="menu-button" style="top: 560px;">Open Menu</button></p>
<div class="menu-wrap" style="top: 700px;">
</div>
<p></p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->


    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <span class="posted-on"><span class="screen-reader-text">Posted on </span><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/17/test-2/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2015-08-17T22:02:36+00:00">August 17, 2015</time><time class="updated" datetime="2015-08-17T23:10:27+00:00">August 17, 2015</time></a></span><span class="comments-link"><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/17/test-2/#respond">Leave a comment</a></span>           </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->

<article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">

    <header class="entry-header">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/15/wordpress-resources-at-siteground/" rel="bookmark">WordPress Resources at SiteGround</a></h2>    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <p>WordPress is an award-winning web software, used by millions of webmasters worldwide for building their website or blog. SiteGround is proud to host this particular WordPress installation and provide users with multiple resources to facilitate the management of their WP websites:</p>
<h3>Expert <a href="http://www.siteground.com/wordpress-hosting.htm">WordPress Hosting</a></h3>
<p>SiteGround provides superior WordPress hosting focused on speed, security and customer service. We take care of WordPress sites security with unique server-level customizations, WP auto-updates, and daily backups. We make them faster by regularly upgrading our hardware, offering free CDN with Railgun and developing our SuperCacher that speeds sites up to 100 times! And last but not least, we provide real WordPress help 24/7! Learn more about SiteGround WordPress hosting</p>
<h3>WordPress tutorial and knowledgebase articles</h3>
<p>WordPress is considered an easy to work with software. Yet, if you are a beginner you might need some help, or you might be looking for tweaks that do not come naturally even to more advanced users. SiteGround <a href="http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/">WordPress tutorial</a> includes installation and theme change instructions, management of WordPress plugins, manual upgrade and backup creation, and more. If you are looking for a more rare setup or modification, you may visit <a href="http://kb.siteground.com">SiteGround Knowledgebase</a>.</p>
<h3><a href="http://www.siteground.com/wordpress-hosting/wordpress-themes.htm">Free WordPress themes</a></h3>
<p>SiteGround experts not only develop various solutions for WordPress sites, but also create unique designs that you could download for free. SiteGround WordPress themes are easy to customize for the particular use of the webmaster.</p>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->


    <footer class="entry-footer">
        <span class="posted-on"><span class="screen-reader-text">Posted on </span><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/15/wordpress-resources-at-siteground/" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="2015-08-15T00:43:01+00:00">August 15, 2015</time></a></span><span class="comments-link"><a href="https://generation-co.co/index.php/2015/08/15/wordpress-resources-at-siteground/#comments">1 Comment</a></span>           </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

</article><!-- #post-## -->

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
    </div><!-- .content-area -->


    </div><!-- .site-content -->

    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
        <div class="site-info">
                        <a href="https://wordpress.org/">Proudly powered by WordPress</a>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </footer><!-- .site-footer -->

</div><!-- .site -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20141010"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var screenReaderText = {"expand":"<span class=\"screen-reader-text\">expand child menu<\/span>","collapse":"<span class=\"screen-reader-text\">collapse child menu<\/span>"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://generation-co.co/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20150330"></script>



</body></html>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and DOM methods?

Answer (score 2):

you defined `openbtn` as a jQuery object not a dom object. You can use `openbtn[0]` to get the dom element or you can use jQuery event handling with `openbtn.on('click', function(){})`

Comment: Now I receive this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined"

Comment: And with the second troubleshoot I receive this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: Can you put your html in to your question?

Comment: This is because you do not have any `.content-wrap` element in your HTML. `document.querySelector('.content-wrap')` returns null

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you are trying to assign addEventListner to an array of objects, you need to loop through it (one way or another) to do so:

Below is working code:

```
/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

(function (window) {

 'use strict';

 // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

 function classReg(className) {
     return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
 }

 // classList support for class management
 // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
 var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

 if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
     hasClass = function (elem, c) {
         return elem.classList.contains(c);
     };
     addClass = function (elem, c) {
         elem.classList.add(c);
     };
     removeClass = function (elem, c) {
         elem.classList.remove(c);
     };
 } else {
     hasClass = function (elem, c) {
         return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
     };
     addClass = function (elem, c) {
         if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
             elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
         }
     };
     removeClass = function (elem, c) {
         elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
     };
 }

 function toggleClass(elem, c) {
     var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
     fn(elem, c);
 }

 var classie = {
     // full names
     hasClass: hasClass,
     addClass: addClass,
     removeClass: removeClass,
     toggleClass: toggleClass,
     // short names
     has: hasClass,
     add: addClass,
     remove: removeClass,
     toggle: toggleClass
 };

 // transport
 if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
     // AMD
     define(classie);
 } else {
     // browser global
     window.classie = classie;
 }

})(window);


 /**
   * main.js
   * http://www.codrops.com
   *
   * Licensed under the MIT license.
   * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
   * 
   * Copyright 2014, Codrops
   * http://www.codrops.com
   */ 
(function () {

 var bodyEl = document.body,
     content = document.querySelector('.content-wrap'),
     openbtn = $(".menu-button").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".menu-wrap").toggleClass("show-menu");
     }),
     closebtn = document.getElementById('close-button'),
     isOpen = false;


 function init() {
     initEvents();
 }

 function initEvents() {
    for (var i=0; i< openbtn.length ; i++){
        openbtn[i].addEventListener('click', toggleMenu)
    }

     if (closebtn) {
         closebtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
     }

      // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or         one of its descendants..
     if (content){
        content.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
             var target = ev.target;
             if (isOpen && target !== openbtn) {
                 toggleMenu();
             }
         });
     }

 }

 function toggleMenu() {
     if (isOpen) {
         classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
     } else {
         classie.add(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
     }
     isOpen = !isOpen;
    }

     init();

 })();
```